# java - linking text resources in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, resources

I want to parse a text file called "hops.txt" which is located in a folder called "res"
inside the main project's folder.

When running the following code:

```
package parsing;

import java.io.InputStream;

public class ParseTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ParseTest pt = new ParseTest();
    pt.foo();
}
public void foo()
{
    InputStream is= this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hops.txt");
    System.out.println(is);
    is= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("hops.txt");
    System.out.println(is);
}
}
```

I recieve the following output:
null
null

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

[image: project layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem by deleting the folder res and putting all the files under a package with the name "res" under the "src" folder.
After that using the code:

```
InputStream is= this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/hops.txt");
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The path parameter of `getResourceAsStream` is assumed to be relative to your project root.  Because this text file is in a folder within your project, you must include the folder name in the resource path.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/hops.txt");
```

Comment: The project root must also be on the classpath, which by default it is not. And I believe the correct path should be `"res/hops.txt". The slash in front makes it absolute.

Comment: both of those ways still return null

Comment: You did not add res folder to classpath.